# Problem with special character apostrophes in java and mysql

Tags: java, mysql, string

i have two string :

```
 name="riyana's dream";
  shopname= "my flower shop name is riyana's dream and it is nice.";
```

now i want to check whether ***shopname*** contains the string  **name** in it or not.
i tried with shopname.contains(name) in java but it didn't work. actually shopname is fetched from mysql database. is it any problem?

please give me some idea about how to test whether shopname contains name in it or not.

Comment: Are you sure exactly the String shopname is in the MySQL-database? I can't believe it.

Comment: I'm with Daniel I'd print out the shopname to see what exactly is coming back from the database.

Comment: I assume one of the apostrophes is not what it seems to be. In unicode there are a lot of very similar characters sometimes of different languages. You should print out the hex codes of each character and see what character you really have: http://www.utf8-chartable.de/

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this?

```
        String name ="riyana's dream";
  String shopName = "my flower shop name is riyana's dream and it is nice.";
        if(shopName.contains(name)){
         System.out.println("Yes");
        }else{
         System.out.println("No");
        }
```

It prints "Yes".

Answer (score 0):

Special characters are no problem in Java. The contains() function works, so the problem is somewhere else.

If you use the JDBC API you can be sure the data is fetched correctly from the database. Please post more of your code.

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is with **contains** method, i tried with your example and did work here is the code:

```
String name="riyana's dream";
String shopname= "my flower shop name is riyana's dream and it is nice.";
if(shopname.contains(name))
   System.out.println("shopname contains the string name");
else
   System.out.println("shopname NOT contains the string name");
```